# Is there a way to add/remove several classes in one single instruction with classList?

Tags: javascript, html

So far I have to do this:

```
elem.classList.add("first");
elem.classList.add("second");
elem.classList.add("third");
```

While this is doable in jQuery, like this

```
$(elem).addClass("first second third");
```

I'd like to know if there's any native way to add or remove.

Answer (score 653, accepted):

```
elem.classList.add("first");
elem.classList.add("second");
elem.classList.add("third");
```

is equal to:

```
elem.classList.add("first", "second", "third");
```

Comment: And if you want to apply an Array of several class-names, you have to call:

DOMTokenList.prototype.add.apply(elem.classList, ['first', 'second', 'third']);

Comment: Firefox doesn't support it either, at the time of writing.  [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23316665/94197) provides a polyfill.

Comment: I am switching to this one as the correct answer, as this is a native API, even if support is not great.

Comment: Have you considered el.className += " my classes here"

Comment: From validation point of view, do we need to check if class which we are trying to add already exist or it internally takes care of that part?

Comment: is there a way to remove multiple classes

Comment: @Vicky [`elem.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)`.remove("first","second","third");` Both `add` and `remove` methods are based on the same `DOMTokenList`.

Answer (score 154):

The new [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) makes it even easier to apply multiple CSS classes as array:

```
const list = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
element.classList.add(...list);
```

Comment: The accepted answer works with a direct list of values, but this one works with arrays... both seem excellent answers!

Comment: Can I use a `DOMTokenList` instead of an array? I know that a DOMTokenList is an array-like object. So it is possible to use it ith the `classList.add()` method or must the DOMTokenList be converted in a real array?

Comment: such a know it all :)

Answer (score 67):

You can do like below

**Add**

```
elem.classList.add("first", "second", "third");

// OR

elem.classList.add(...["first","second","third"]);
```

**Remove**

```
elem.classList.remove("first", "second", "third");

// OR

elem.classList.remove(...["first","second","third"]);
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: You don't need to check the existence first. The [docs say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove): "If the string is not in the list, no error is thrown, and nothing happens."

Answer (score 24):

The `classList` property ensures that duplicate classes are not unnecessarily added to the element. In order to keep this functionality, if you dislike the longhand versions or jQuery version, I'd suggest adding an `addMany` function and `removeMany` to `DOMTokenList` (the type of `classList`):

```
DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany = function(classes) {
    var array = classes.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
      this.add(array[i]);
    }
}

DOMTokenList.prototype.removeMany = function(classes) {
    var array = classes.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, length = array.length; i < length; i++) {
      this.remove(array[i]);
    }
}
```

These would then be useable like so:

```
elem.classList.addMany("first second third");
elem.classList.removeMany("first third");
```

**Update**

As per your comments, if you wish to only write a custom method for these in the event they are not defined, try the following:

```
DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany = DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany || function(classes) {...}
DOMTokenList.prototype.removeMany = DOMTokenList.prototype.removeMany || function(classes) {...}
```

Comment: Still a good answer. And I couldn't edit it for you as it was only 2 characters.

Answer (score 20):

Since the `add()` method from the `classList` just allows to pass separate arguments and not a single array, you need to invoque `add()` using apply. For the first argument you will need to pass the `classList` reference from the same DOM node and as a second argument the array of classes that you want to add:

```
element.classList.add.apply(
  element.classList,
  ['class-0', 'class-1', 'class-2']
);
```

Comment: It's ES5 version of solution with the [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) (see @morkro [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36486683/6125971)). 
Check it easily at [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/).

Answer (score 15):

Here is a work around for IE 10 and 11 users that seemed pretty straight forward.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem');

['first','second','third'].forEach(item => elem.classList.add(item));
```

```html
<div id="elem">Hello World!</div>
```

Or

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('elem'),
    classes = ['first','second','third'];

classes.forEach(function(item) {
    elem.classList.add(item);
});
```

```html
<div id="elem">Hello World!</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

To add class to a element

```
document.querySelector(elem).className+=' first second third';
```

Remove a class

```
document.querySelector(elem).className=document.querySelector(elem).className.split(class_to_be_removed).join(" ");
```

Comment: This is interesting to know, but all it does is to edit the string of the class. It wouldnt work if I wanted to remove several classes. Sorry, I forgot to add that in the OP.

Comment: Do **NOT** use `className`. It is terrible for performance (even retrieving its value causes a reflow).

Answer (score 7):

Newer versions of the [DOMTokenList spec](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-domtokenlist) allow for multiple arguments to `add()` and `remove()`, as well as a second argument to `toggle()` to force state.

At the time of writing, Chrome supports multiple arguments to `add()` and `remove()`, but none of the other browsers do.  IE 10 and lower, Firefox 23 and lower, Chrome 23 and lower and other browsers do not support the second argument to `toggle()`.

I wrote the following small polyfill to tide me over until support expands:

```
(function () {
    /*global DOMTokenList */
    var dummy  = document.createElement('div'),
        dtp    = DOMTokenList.prototype,
        toggle = dtp.toggle,
        add    = dtp.add,
        rem    = dtp.remove;

    dummy.classList.add('class1', 'class2');

    // Older versions of the HTMLElement.classList spec didn't allow multiple
    // arguments, easy to test for
    if (!dummy.classList.contains('class2')) {
        dtp.add    = function () {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, add.bind(this));
        };
        dtp.remove = function () {
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, rem.bind(this));
        };
    }

    // Older versions of the spec didn't have a forcedState argument for
    // `toggle` either, test by checking the return value after forcing
    if (!dummy.classList.toggle('class1', true)) {
        dtp.toggle = function (cls, forcedState) {
            if (forcedState === undefined)
                return toggle.call(this, cls);

            (forcedState ? add : rem).call(this, cls);
            return !!forcedState;
        };
    }
})();
```

A modern browser with ES5 compliance and `DOMTokenList` are expected, but I'm using this polyfill in several specifically targeted environments, so it works great for me, but it might need tweaking for scripts that will run in legacy browser environments such as IE 8 and lower.

Comment: Nobody seems to mention that IE10 doesn't allow for multiple classes to be added.  This worked nicely for me so thanks!   I would caution though that in IE9 I get an error that DomTokenList is not defined.  You may want to account for that too.  Or only run this  if( typeof DomTokenList !== 'undefined')

Comment: @Ryan: thanks, I thought DOMTokenList was supported in IE 9 but I guess it was missed.  I'll try and investigate a workaround at some point.

Comment: Looks like on a failed DOMTokenList you'd have to use className with word boundary regEx checks

Answer (score 3):

A very simple, non fancy, but working solution that I would have to believe is very cross browser:

Create this function

```js
function removeAddClasses(classList,removeCollection,addCollection){
    for (var i=0;i<removeCollection.length;i++){ 
        classList.remove(removeCollection[i]); 
    }
    for (var i=0;i<addCollection.length;i++){ 
        classList.add(addCollection[i]); 
    }
}
```

Call it like this:
removeAddClasses(node.classList,arrayToRemove,arrayToAdd);

...where arrayToRemove is an array of class names to remove:
['myClass1','myClass2'] etcetera

...and arrayToAdd is an array of class names to add:
['myClass3','myClass4'] etcetera

Answer (score 3):

A better way to add the multiple classes separated by spaces in a string is using the [Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) with the [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```
element.classList.add(...classesStr.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard definiton allows only for adding or deleting a single class. A couple of small wrapper functions can do what you ask :

```
function addClasses (el, classes) {
  classes = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, 1);
  console.log (classes);
  for (var i = classes.length; i--;) {
    classes[i] = classes[i].trim ().split (/\s*,\s*|\s+/);
    for (var j = classes[i].length; j--;)
      el.classList.add (classes[i][j]);
  }
}

function removeClasses (el, classes) {
  classes = Array.prototype.slice.call (arguments, 1);
  for (var i = classes.length; i--;) {
    classes[i] = classes[i].trim ().split (/\s*,\s*|\s+/);
    for (var j = classes[i].length; j--;)
      el.classList.remove (classes[i][j]);
  }
}
```

These wrappers allow you to specify the list of classes as separate arguments, as strings with space or comma separated items, or a combination. For an example see http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/eCqy7

Answer (score 2):

Assume that you have an array of classes to being added, you can use ES6 spread syntax:

`let classes = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
elem.classList.add(...classes);`

Answer (score 2):

I found a very simple method which is more modern and elegant way.

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.m-element');

// To toggle
['class1', 'class2'].map((e) => el.classList.toggle(e));

// To add
['class1', 'class2'].map((e) => el.classList.add(e));

// To remove
['class1', 'class2'].map((e) => el.classList.remove(e));
```

Good thing is you can extend the class array or use any coming from API easily.

Comment: Prefer `forEach` over `map` when you're ignoring the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Another polyfill for `element.classList` is [here](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js/). I found it via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

I include that script and use `element.classList.add("first","second","third")` as it's intended.

Answer (score 0):

One of the **best solution** is to check if an element exists and then proceed to add or possibly remove and above all if the **element is empty**, **delete** it.

```js
/**
 * @description detect if obj is an element
 * @param {*} obj
 * @returns {Boolean}
 * @example
 * see below
 */
function isElement(obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object') {
    return false
  }
  let prototypeStr, prototype
  do {
    prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
    // to work in iframe
    prototypeStr = Object.prototype.toString.call(prototype)
    // '[object Document]' is used to detect document
    if (
      prototypeStr === '[object Element]' ||
      prototypeStr === '[object Document]'
    ) {
      return true
    }
    obj = prototype
    // null is the terminal of object
  } while (prototype !== null)
    return false
}

/*
 * Add multiple class
 * addClasses(element,['class1','class2','class3'])
 * el: element | document.querySelector(".mydiv");
 * classes: passing:: array or string : [] | 'cl1,cl2' | 'cl1 cl2' | 'cl1|cl2'
 */
function addClasses(el, classes) {
  classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  if ( isElement(el) ){ //if (document.body.contains(el)
    for (var i = classes.length; i--;) {
      classes[i] = Array.isArray(classes[i]) ? classes[i]: classes[i].trim().split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/);
      for (var j = classes[i].length; j--;)
        el.classList.add(classes[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Remove multiple class
 * Remove attribute class is empty
 * addClasses(element,['class1','class2','class3'])
 * el: element | document.querySelector(".mydiv");
 * classes: passing:: array or string : [] | 'cl1,cl2' | 'cl1 cl2' | 'cl1|cl2'
 */
function removeClasses(el, classes) {
  classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
  if ( isElement(el) ) {
    for (var i = classes.length; i--;) {
      classes[i] = Array.isArray(classes[i]) ? classes[i]: classes[i].trim().split(/\s*,\s*|\s+/);
      for (var j = classes[i].length; j--;)
        el.classList.remove(classes[i][j]);
        let cl = el.className.trim();
        if (!cl){
          el.removeAttribute('class');
        }
    }
  }
}

var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = 'test'; // div.setAttribute("id", "test");
div.textContent = 'The World';
//div.className = 'class';
// possible use: afterend, beforeend
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', div); 

// Everything written above you can do so:
//document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="text"></div>');

var el = document.querySelector("#test");
addClasses(el,'one,two,three,four');
removeClasses(el,'two,two,never,other');
el.innerHTML = 'I found: '+el.className;
// return : I found: four three one
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I liked @rich.kelly's answer, but I wanted to use the same nomenclature as `classList.add()` (comma seperated strings), so a slight deviation.

```
DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany = DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany || function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    this.add(arguments[i]);
  }
}
DOMTokenList.prototype.removeMany = DOMTokenList.prototype.removeMany || function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    this.remove(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

So you can then use:

```
document.body.classList.addMany('class-one','class-two','class-three');
```

I need to test all browsers, but this worked for Chrome.
 Should we be checking for something more specific than the existence of `DOMTokenList.prototype.addMany`? What exactly causes `classList.add()` to fail in IE11?