# how to remove multiple class using variable

Tags: javascript

i've got snippet for this

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("class", ev.target.classList);
}

function drop(ev, id, classelement) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  var classs = ev.dataTransfer.getData("class");
  document.getElementById(id).classList.add(classs);
  var classel = String(classelement);
  var claskurang = classs.slice(0, classs.length - 1);
  if (classel.includes(claskurang)) {
    var hapus = claskurang + "1" + claskurang + "2" + claskurang + "3";
    alert(hapus);
    document.getElementById(id).classList.remove(hapus);
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 700px;
}

.hamburger {
  float: right;
  font-size: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .5s;
}

.hamburger:hover {
  background-color: #00AAFD;
  color: white;
}

#content {
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: #00AAFD;
  float: right;
  width: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
}

#content h3 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#content div {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.image1 {
  background-color: #3b5998;
}

.image2 {
  background-color: mediumpurple;
}

.image3 {
  background-color: #1dc116;
}

.border1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border2 {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.border3 {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}

.fcolor1 {
  color: lightgreen;
}

.fcolor2 {
  color: #1d9c23;
}

.fcolor3 {
  color: #5e5e5e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="div1" ondrop="drop(event,this.id,this.classList)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
  <p id="asd"></p>
  <div class="fitur">
    <div id="content">
      <h3><b>Background Color</b></h3>
      <div class="image1" id="body" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <div class="image2" id="body" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <div class="image3" id="body" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <h3><b>Table Border</b></h3>
      <div class="border1" id="table" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <div class="border2" id="table" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <div class="border3" id="table" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <h3><b>Font Color</b></h3>
      <div class="fcolor1" id="font" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Lorem</div>
      <div class="fcolor2" id="font" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Lorem</div>
      <div class="fcolor3" id="font" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Lorem</div>
      <span class="hamburger">=</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" placeholder="ID" readonly>
    <input type="text" id="nama" name="nama" placeholder="Nama">
    <input type="text" id="kelas" name="kelas" placeholder="kelas" />
    <input type="button" id="cmd" value="Insert" onclick="displayResult(this.value)">
    <input type="button" id="clear" value="Clear data" onclick="cleardata()">
    <table id="myTable" border="1" ondrop="drop(event,this.id,this.class)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nama</td>
        <td>Kelas </td>
        <td>Button</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="isi">
    </div>
</body>
```

this is my main code that i've got problem with

```
function drop(ev,id,classelement) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        var classs = ev.dataTransfer.getData("class");
        document.getElementById(id).classList.add(classs);
        var classel = String(classelement);
        var claskurang = classs.slice(0,classs.length -1);
         if(classel.includes(claskurang)) {
         var hapus = claskurang+"1"+claskurang+"2"+claskurang+"3";
            document.getElementById(id).classList.remove(hapus);
        }

    }
```

i've try to give space after claskurang like `claskurang+"1 "` but it still error and the console says this
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRkX0.png)
and this is the output when i alert the variable "hapus"
[output when var hapus alerted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycGoC.png)
well actually i want to make a drag and drop and i want to remove the class that has been same as class that is in the element, for example if i add border class to body element, i want to remove ONLY the border class and replace it into the class that i add (using drag and drop)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: should it not be `claskurang+"1,"+claskurang+"2,"+claskurang+"3";` Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Examples

Comment: There is no jQuery here. Tags removed

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @luca i want to make a drag and drop and i want to remove the class that has been same as class that is in the element, for example if i add border class to body element, i want to remove ONLY the border class and replace it into the class that i add (using drag and drop)

Comment: The error has already been corrected by @CarstenLøvboAndersen - but why load jQuery if you do not use it at all in your code? Or if you have other code why is this code not jQuery

Comment: What you are looking for is `el.classList.remove('className1', 'className2', 'className3',...)`

Comment: @mplungjan because i thought that the solution can be in jquery instead of javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to add/remove several classes in one single instruction with classList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115998/is-there-a-way-to-add-remove-several-classes-in-one-single-instruction-with-clas)

Comment: @Rajesh classname so if i put `'className1'` in variabel i need to remove the quote?

Comment: @EricAnthonyWu Yes. Essentially, you would need 1 variable per class.