# How to manipulate css using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to manipulate the css when clicking on button using javascript . I want to just make a single button active the one which is recently clicked.

I am able to make it active but somehow i am not able to remove active for other which is not selected

here is what i tried in js

```js
const myFunction = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target
  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.lightblue')
  allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('.btn.lightblue.active'))
  clickedElem.classList.add('active')
}
```

```html
<p> 
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">XASD</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">QWER</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">ASDF</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">ZXCV</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115998/is-there-a-way-to-add-remove-several-classes-in-one-single-instruction-with-clas

Answer (score 3):

Look at the definition of the [`remove` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove):

> ```
> tokenList.remove(token1[, token2[, ...tokenN]]);
> ```

It takes each class that you want to remove as a **separate** argument (strings with one class name in each).

It doesn't take a single argument with a CSS selector.

… and you probably only want to remove the `active` class anyway, not `btn` or `lightblue`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `remove` function on `btn.classList.remove`, pls put `className` only.

```js
const myFunction = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target
  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.lightblue')
  allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'))
  clickedElem.classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p> 
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">XASD</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">QWER</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">ASDF</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)" class="btn lightblue">ZXCV</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use 1) Element.style = "..." or 2) Element.classList.add("...")

to

1. overwrite the css with the style attribute
2. add a class to the element to have it use a predefined styling. (note that elements can have multiple classes)

Comment: Setting the `style` properly doesn't make sense given that the question is specifically about the `active` class.

Comment: Setting `Element.class` won't do anything. That isn't what the property is called.