# jQuery inside an event using classList

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I press a `<button>`, I want to wait for an asynchronous function, then add some classes to the `<button>`, but it doesn't work. I want to use jQuery to do this.

Here is my code:

```
$("#btnSta").addEventListener("click", () => {
    getAccount().then(addresses => {
        $("#btnSta").classList.add('opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML and CSS code too?

Comment: @MichaelM. isn't needed, is a typo. he need to pass multiple strings instead of space on one string. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115998/is-there-a-way-to-add-remove-several-classes-in-one-single-instruction-with-clas so ❌ `.add("class1 class2")` -> ✅ `.add("class1", "class2", "class3")`. **EDIT:** see the @michael answer because with jquery only approach it will work fine, so not use DOM js vanilla with jquery said in the answer

Comment: @MichaelM. ahaha right, thats the problem. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine the DOM API (`.classList`) with jQuery. Instead, you should only use jQuery functions. The equivalent jQuery is this:

```js
async function getAccount() {
  // .. do something ..
  return null; // just for the example
}

$("#btnSta").click(async () => {
  const addresses = await getAccount();
  $("#btnSta").addClass('opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed');
});
```

```css
.opacity-50 {
  opacity: 50%;
}

.cursor-not-allowed {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnSta">Test</button>
```

You can also change your `.then` statement to the newer async/await syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As noted you are referencing vanila javascript methods on jquery selectors. Change parts

```
$("#btnSta").addEventListener("click",
```

to

```
$("#btnSta").on("click",
```

and

```
$("#btnSta").classList.add('opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed')
```

to

```
$("#btnSta").addClass('opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed')
```