# javascript not adding class to div

Tags: javascript

```
<div 
  id="overlay_block" 
  class="overlay-type overlay" 
  data-text-placement="{{ block.settings.overlay_position }}" 
  data-mobile-text-placement="{{ block.settings.overlay_mobile }}">
</div>
```

and this bit of javascript that should add/remove the div class on window resize.

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");
var overlayBlock = document.getElementById("overlay_block");
var textPlacement = overlayBlock.getAttribute("data-text-placement");
var mobileTextPlacement = overlayBlock.getAttribute("data-mobile-text-placement");
console.log("textPlacement: ", textPlacement);
console.log("mobileTextPlacement: ", mobileTextPlacement);
if (mq.matches) {
  overlayBlock.classList.add(mobileTextPlacement);
  overlayBlock.classList.remove(textPlacement);
} else {
  overlayBlock.classList.add(textPlacement);
  overlayBlock.classList.remove(mobileTextPlacement);
}
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    overlayBlock.classList.add(mobileTextPlacement);
    overlayBlock.classList.remove(textPlacement);
  } else {
    overlayBlock.classList.add(textPlacement);
    overlayBlock.classList.remove(mobileTextPlacement);
  }
});
```

As you can see from the code I have logged to console the variables that contains the class that should be added to the div and they contain the correct values that are the css class i need to add:

```
textPlacement:  position--left position--top
mobileTextPlacement:  position--right position--bottom
```

Also if i replace one of the statements (e.g. `overlayBlock.classList.add(textPlacement)` with a string `overlayBlock.classList.add("some text")`
the string gets added correctly to the div class. Any hint on how to fix my code?

PS: I'd prefer to avoid using jquery

Any help appreciated

Comment: Please format the code properly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: `textPlacement:  position--left position--top` - `classList.add` does not work with _one_ value that contains multiple class names. Each parameter needs to be a single valid class name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint. You mean {{ block.settings.overlay_position }} and {{ block.settings.overlay_mobile }} ? those are liquid schema variables. When I output those to console I get the correct values: textPlacement: return position--left position--top
mobileTextPlacement returns position--right position--bottom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to add/remove several classes in one single instruction with classList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115998/is-there-a-way-to-add-remove-several-classes-in-one-single-instruction-with-clas)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to @CBroe hint I manager to fix my code. Here is the correct script

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");
var overlayBlock = document.getElementById("overlay_block");
var textPlacement = overlayBlock.getAttribute("data-text-placement");
var mobileTextPlacement = overlayBlock.getAttribute("data-mobile-text-placement");

var addClasses = function(elem, classList) {
  var classes = classList.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    elem.classList.add(classes[i]);
  }
};

var removeClasses = function(elem, classList) {
  var classes = classList.split(" ");
  for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    elem.classList.remove(classes[i]);
  }
};

if (mq.matches) {
  addClasses(overlayBlock, mobileTextPlacement);
  removeClasses(overlayBlock, textPlacement);
} else {
  addClasses(overlayBlock, textPlacement);
  removeClasses(overlayBlock, mobileTextPlacement);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    addClasses(overlayBlock, mobileTextPlacement);
    removeClasses(overlayBlock, textPlacement);
  } else {
    addClasses(overlayBlock, textPlacement);
    removeClasses(overlayBlock, mobileTextPlacement);
  }
});
```

Comment: If `classes` is an array of strings, instead of your loop, you can just do `elem.classList.add([...classes])` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList  (which also the linked duplicate will tell you)

Comment: so you mean I could just amend my original code replacing (mobileTextPlacement) with (...mobileTextPlacement) and (textPlacement)with (...textPlacement) ? seems great !

Comment: no, not `mobileTextPlacement` because thats a string, but you can do `overlayBlock.classList.add(...mobileTextPlacement.split(" "))`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the final piece of working code, definitely more elegant than the previous loop. With a simple mod to the original code.

```
var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 767px)");
var overlayBlock = document.getElementById("overlay_block");
var textPlacement = overlayBlock.getAttribute("data-text-placement").split(" ");
var mobileTextPlacement = overlayBlock.getAttribute("data-mobile-text-placement").split(" ");

if (mq.matches) {
  overlayBlock.classList.add(...mobileTextPlacement);
  overlayBlock.classList.remove(...textPlacement);
} else {
  overlayBlock.classList.add(...textPlacement);
  overlayBlock.classList.remove(...mobileTextPlacement);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 767) {
    overlayBlock.classList.add(...mobileTextPlacement);
    overlayBlock.classList.remove(...textPlacement);
  } else {
    overlayBlock.classList.add(...textPlacement);
    overlayBlock.classList.remove(...mobileTextPlacement);
  }
});
```